# 502 Proxy error in Orders page Magento 2.0.10

Tags: magento2

I recently upgraded from 2.0.6 to 2.0.10 and thought everything went alright, but since then, admin users experience a 502 proxy error when trying to access the orders page.

[image]
[image]

I'm not able to reproduce the problem myself, each time it seems related to a specific account. If I log in, go to the orders page and user the same filter, it'll work.

The only workaround I found until now is to log with the problematic user, inspect the code of the page, delete the loading overlay and clear the filters.

Any idea?